# How to make HTTP POST on website that uses asp.net?

Tags: python, asp.net, http, http-post, python-requests

I'm using Python library `requests` for this, but I can't seem to be able to log in to this website.
The url is https://www.bet365affiliates.com/ui/pages/affiliates/, and I've been trying post requests to https://www.bet365affiliates.com/Members/CMSitePages/SiteLogin.aspx?lng=1 with the data of "ctl00$MasterHeaderPlaceHolder$ctl00$passwordTextbox", "ctl00$MasterHeaderPlaceHolder$ctl00$userNameTextbox", etc, but I never seem to be able to get logged in.

Could someone more experienced check the page's source code and tell me what am I am missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution could be this: Please Take attention, you could do it without selenium. If you want to do without it, firstly you should get the main affiliate page, and from the response data you could fetch all the required information (which I gather by xpaths). I just didn't have enough time to write it in fully requests.

To gather the informations from response data you could use XML tree library. With the same XPATH method, you could easily find all the requested informations.

```
import requests
from selenium import webdriver

Password = 'YOURPASS'
Username = 'YOURUSERNAME'

browser = webdriver.Chrome(os.getcwd()+"/"+"Chromedriver.exe")
browser.get('https://www.bet365affiliates.com/ui/pages/affiliates/Affiliates.aspx')
VIEWSTATE=browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="__VIEWSTATE"]')
SESSIONID=browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="CMSessionId"]')
PREVPAG=browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="__PREVIOUSPAGE"]')
EVENTVALIDATION=browser.find_element_by_xpath('//* [@id="__EVENTVALIDATION"]')
cookies = browser.get_cookies()

session = requests.session()
for cookie in cookies:
    print cookie['name']
    print cookie['value']
    session.cookies.set(cookie['name'], cookie['value'])   

payload = {'ctl00_AjaxScriptManager_HiddenField':'',
           '__EVENTTARGET':'ctl00$MasterHeaderPlaceHolder$ctl00$goButton',
           '__EVENTARGUMENT':'',
           '__VIEWSTATE':VIEWSTATE,
           '__PREVIOUSPAGE':PREVPAG,
           '__EVENTVALIDATION':EVENTVALIDATION,
           'txtPassword':Username,
           'txtUserName':Password,
           'CMSessionId':SESSIONID,
           'returnURL':'/ui/pages/affiliates/Affiliates.aspx',
           'ctl00$MasterHeaderPlaceHolder$ctl00$userNameTextbox':Username,
           'ctl00$MasterHeaderPlaceHolder$ctl00$passwordTextbox':Password,
           'ctl00$MasterHeaderPlaceHolder$ctl00$tempPasswordTextbox':'Password'}


session.post('https://www.bet365affiliates.com/Members/CMSitePages/SiteLogin.aspx?lng=1',data=payload)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for taking your time to write this, but unfortunately it still doesn't work. I fixed on your code the VIEWSTATE=browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="__VIEWSTATE"]' to have a .get_attribute('value') in the end, but still it doesn't log in.

Comment: I decided to give up with requests and just use Selenium for the whole task, since it works..

Comment: actually, I found an intermediary solution that is working now! I'm using selenium with phantomjs to log in, and then use those cookies with requests, then it works. I think since the website requires some javascript function to log in, requests can't do it, but once the cookies are set it's all good! thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Did you inspected the http request used by the browser to log you in?
You should replicate it.

FB

Comment: I did, but I may be missing something here.. Should I just be making my post request with everything that Chrome shows on the "Form data" part?

Comment: Yes. Be sure no sort of cookies are involved.

Comment: And you should use the same headers too.

Comment: I tried it, but it's still not working.. I think I'll just give up

Comment: Please attach the Chrome's networking tab requests, and we could solve it for you :)