# Login using python request module on a aspx webpage

Tags: python-2.7, authentication, python-requests

I've being trying to log in to this [web page](https://www.scadalynx.com/GlobalLogin.aspx) but I fail every time. This is the code i used

```
import requests

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Chrome'}
payload = {'_GlobalLoginControl$UserLogin':'myUser','_GlobalLoginControl$Password':'myPass'}

s = requests.Session()
r = s.post('https://www.scadalynx.com/GlobalLogin.aspx',headers=headers,data=payload)
r = s.get('https://www.scadalynx.com/Default.aspx')
print r.url
```

The result I get from: `print r.url` is this:

```
https://www.scadalynx.com/GlobalLogin.aspx?Timeout=Y
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.
The main problem is, your payload isn't complete. Check chrome's networking tab. There are much more required payloads.

```
ScriptMgr:_GlobalLoginControl$UpdatePanel1|_GlobalLoginControl$LoginBtn
ScriptMgr_HiddenField:;;AjaxControlToolkit, Version=4.1.40412.0,     Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e:en-US:2d0688b9-5fe7-418f-aeb1-6ecaa4dca45f:475a4ef5:effe2a26:751cdd15:5546a2b:dfad98a5:1d3ed089:497ef277:a43b07eb:3cf12cf1
__EVENTTARGET:
__EVENTARGUMENT:
__VIEWSTATE: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
__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR:ABDC7715
__SCROLLPOSITIONX:0
__SCROLLPOSITIONY:0
__EVENTVALIDATION:/wEdAA8j+x15hTpBOEjDv1LxVan3AUijrFjxy9PpisoGxfMqnNduSMVw1RChh3aZsdCK82jXRUWkWThaqEhU3Gr5iw98GHoUhEtg6gp73QcFIR1tGEGQHmQGQos+5LR8l78kIyNCGm6wvkKBlG3Z3EngFWzmX3gMRUNTCvY9T8lfFGMsRkvp3s0LtAU9sya5EgaP5MNrqxxx0HTfWwHJy49saUYlPDg6OL5q3VoZ6biOkvIG8l/ujxMESq+8VmX4sGwXcQBJxOm7RbAd1IEojVITrtk4hx8VhfPuqTNrqWHRrUAMgBj1ffXkwiR7kcJxJ3ixy43iLukJszI09WI7xsAFyAKxG82PcA==
_GlobalLoginControl$ScrWidth:1536
_GlobalLoginControl$ScrHeight:864
_GlobalLoginControl$UserLogin:asdsad@asdas.com
_GlobalLoginControl$Password:asdasd
_GlobalLoginControl$PasswordStore:
_GlobalLoginControl$HiddenField1:
_GlobalLoginControl$_HiddenSessionContentID:
_ErrorHiddenField:
__ASYNCPOST:true
_GlobalLoginControl$LoginBtn:Login
```

Probably, you could outsource this (I think it isn't possible, you have to use selenium or get the page first and scrape the informations.

But check this topic: [How to make HTTP POST on website that uses asp.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43137900/how-to-make-http-post-on-website-that-uses-asp-net/43142300?noredirect=1#comment73391499_43142300)

We considered that, the login should be pass-through with phantomjs/chrome with selenium, the you should pass the cookies and the headers to requests. After you pass the required informations for requests, you could work with request for the further steps.

Comment: Thanks for the info