# POST data to aspx form using apache python Requests library and scrape user data with BeautifulSoup

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to POST data to ASPX form using the Python requests library. But I'm not able to get it right. My plan is to scrape user data, e.g. name, address, etc.

Here is the web form: https://www.icsi.in/student/Members/MemberSearch.aspx - I am searching only with one input: "CP Number" = 16803.

Here is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def make_request_to_url():
    url = "https://www.icsi.in/student/Members/MemberSearch.aspx"
    post_data = {
        'dnn$ctr410$MemberSearch$txtFirstName': None,
        'dnn$ctr410$MemberSearch$txtLastName': None,
        'dnn$ctr410$MemberSearch$ddlMemberType': None,
        'dnn$ctr410$MemberSearch$txtMembershipNumber': None,
        'dnn$ctr410$MemberSearch$txtCpNumber': 16803,
        'dnn$ctr410$MemberSearch$txtCity': None,
        'dnn$ctr410$MemberSearch$txtOrganisation': None,
        'dnn$ctr410$MemberSearch$txtAddress2': None,            
        'dnn$ctr410$MemberSearch$txtAddress3': None,
        'dnn$ctr410$MemberSearch$txtEmail': None
    }
    r = requests.post(url, data = post_data)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,'lxml')
    head_name =  soup.find_all("div",{"class":"name_head"})
    print "head_name",head_name
```

I get content but not the required data line with name, address, etc. to scrape. What to do?

Comment: i found this useful link:                                                        https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43149898/login-using-python-request-module-on-a-aspx-webpage/43188546

Comment: instead of data, use json. like r = requests.post(url, json= post_data). This might help.

Comment: not working with r = requests.post(url, json= post_data)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send a "multipart/form-data" with requests in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12385179/how-to-send-a-multipart-form-data-with-requests-in-python)

Comment: Your web form requires the the `multipart/form-data` content type, but the `requests` module sends HTTP POST requests as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` by default. See the [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12385179/18771) for the way to send the form in the server expects.